# Giving wrong day of week in PHP

Tags: php, date, dayofweek

It is displaying Thursday but Wednesday output, please help me fix it.........

My **code**

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $date = '2017/06/07';
    $weekday = date('l', strtotime($date)); 
    echo $weekday; //
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use this **$date = '2017/07/06';** yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: $date = '2017-06-07';  tried but not working @Dave

Comment: Use date as 2017-07-06. (Y-m-d) format

Comment: working fine on my system, writephponline, and eval.in..
working fine both ways Y/m/d as well as Y-m-d

Comment: @vinod check this  :: https://eval.in/828529

Comment: got it thanks.....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use date format "Y-m-d" to get the result you want.
 **$date = '2017/06/07'** means June 07, 2017.

If you want to get the day of July 06, 2017 then change

```
$date = '2017/06/07';
```

To

```
$date = '2017/07/06';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = '2017/06/07';
$date = str_replace('/','-', $date);
$weekday = date('l', strtotime($date)); 
echo $weekday;
// Output: Wednesday
```

[Phpfiddle link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6570aac5183f24038841f24907637d41072b839)

[Check the document here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d. To
>   avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.